Average number of users per days in selected time period, but only having HLL value at hand
Example of rows in the the table:



derived_date
brand_cleaned
platform_cleaned
user_id_hll




2024-07-01
ABC
Desktop
6D0004C100010E01037C0101B60103C00101E50102000201380201DD0203280302360


2024-07-01
DEF
Tablet
A90601


2024-07-01
DEF
Mobile
DB0204DA0604C20802040901090902



I have the following LookML code:
view: view_example {
  derived_table: {
    sql:  select
            derived_date,
            brand_cleaned,
            platform_cleaned,
            user_id_hll,
            hll_combine(user_id_hll) over (partition by fact.brand_cleaned, fact.derived_date) as total_user_hll,
            from production.example.table
            where
                        {% condition device_cleaned %} device_cleaned {% endcondition %}
                    and {% condition derived_date_date%} derived_date {% endcondition %}
                    and {% condition platform_cleaned%} platform_cleaned {% endcondition %}
                    and {% condition operating_system_cleaned%} operating_system_cleaned {% endcondition %}
    ;;
  }

  measure: days_in_selected_period {
    description: "Number of days in your selected period"
    group_label: "System"
    type: count_distinct
    sql: ${derived_date_date} ;;
  }

  dimension: user_id_hll {
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}."USER_ID_HLL" ;;
  }

  measure: unique_users_approx {
    type: number
    sql: hll_estimate(hll_combine(${user_id_hll})) ;;
  }

  measure: total_users_approx {
    type: number
    sql: hll_estimate(hll_combine(${TABLE}.total_user_hll)) ;;
  }

}

I use total_users_approx in my dashboard to show the total number of unique users in the selected date range.
But I would actually want to show a daily average instead. Simply dividing this number by days_in_selected_period would not be accurate since users could be visiting on multiple days, and are only being counted once in total_users_approx.
How can I create a measure that calculates the average number of daily users? The table I am working with doesn't contain an actual user number, just the user_id_hll.

It sounds like your derived table query needs to be modified to get an aggregated count of users per day first. Then in the Explore for this derived table you can average the value of those daily counts using a measure
